# Issue in my swift project validating form

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm having issues with validating my form for example when the form is empty and I click the save button it disable the button which is right. When I type some values into my form and click the save button does not perform the action inside the button. I'm not sure why it is not working.

Function

```
private func ValidateForm(title: UITextField , description: UITextView, category: UITextField){
    if title.text!.isEmpty && description.text.isEmpty && category.text!.isEmpty {
        saveBtn.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        saveBtn.isEnabled = true
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ValidateForm(title: titleTextField, description: descriptionTextView, category: categoryTextField)
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `validateForm` from any other places? I.e. when any of the 3 text fields/views change their input, you need to recall validate.

Comment: I only call validateForm in the view did load

Comment: Thanks i have figured it out i forgot to put the validateForm in the textFieldDidEndEditing, textViewDidEndEditing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't call `validateForm` once the input to your text fields/text view changes. You need to make your view controller conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UITextViewDelegate`, then set `self` as the delegate for all 3 text fields/view and call the validate method from the appropriate delegate functions, `textFieldDidEndEditing` and `textViewDidEndEditing`.

```
class FormViewController: UIViewController {
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        validateForm(title: titleTextField, description: descriptionTextView, category: categoryTextField)
        titleTextField.delegate = self
        categoryTextField.delegate = self
        descriptionTextView.delegate = self
    }

    func validateForm(title: UITextField, description: UITextView, category: UITextField) {
        let invalid = title.text!.isEmpty && description.text.isEmpty && category.text!.isEmpty
        saveButton.isEnabled = !invalid
    }
}

extension FormViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        validateForm(title: titleTextField, description: descriptionTextView, category: categoryTextField)
    }
}

extension FormViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        validateForm(title: titleTextField, description: descriptionTextView, category: categoryTextField)
    }
}
```